# How to improve function performance in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have function below but using it in a select and then inserting the value into temp table is too slow so I try to update to make better performance.

I think it's slow because it selects and then inserts into temp table. If I execute the script without function, it is fast, but I need it to use other place the same table.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FN_GET_CUSTOMER_INFO] 
     (@CUSTID VARCHAR(MAX)) 
RETURNS 
     @TBL TABLE (CUSTID VARCHAR(200),CUSTNAME NVARCHAR(200))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @STATUS VARCHAR(200)

    SELECT @STATUS = [STATUS] 
    FROM TBL_CUSTOMER 
    WHERE CUSTID = @CUSTID

    IF @STATUS = 'INCLUDE'
    BEGIN   
        INSERT INTO @TBL
            SELECT * 
            FROM TBL_CUSTOMER 
            WHERE CUSTID = @CUSTID
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @TBL
            SELECT * 
            FROM TBL_CUSTOMER 
            WHERE CUSTID = @CUSTID 
              AND GENDER = 'M'
    END
END
```

Comment: please share execution plan as xml and table definition's involved

Comment: I don't have plan

Comment: you can get a plan ,if you dont have one  in ssms,also post table definitions and some test data